# MySQL Queries - Display information created by 'sys'

Tags: mysql

I'm learning to work with databases and have been learning to write queries based on the tables created. 
I'm trying to display information about all the views that were created by the sys user.

I've tried Information_Schema but it returns results that I've created and not the 'sys'.

I'm not sure if I'm attempting it correctly, but I'm getting a result with;

```
EXEC sp_tables
     @table_owner ='sys';
```

but as it still displays everything and not just 'view' - when I try;

```
EXEC sp_tables
@table_owner ='sys',
@table_type = 'view';
```

It returns no data.
Not sure how to work this one out. Tried many things but all were wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I got this right but have tried :

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views where TABLE_schema='sys'
```